# Search for multiple columns with Doctrine Query Builder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have columns that contain entries of the following form:

```sql
col1    |   col2 |   col3
dog         123      bunny
cat         456      table
bunny       789      laptop
```

and I have a search term. Assume it is `bunny`, then i would like to return all the rows that contain the word `bunny` in any of their columns. In this case that would be rows 1 and 3.

All the columns are of the form:

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $col1;
```

I'm still new to doctrine query builder so that is making it hard to begin but I'm thinking it should be something of the following form (but maybe i'm oversimplifying it):

```
        foreach ($this->columns as $column)
        {
            // the problem is my columns don't have the entry property nor do I have the $row as an object
            $queryBuilder->andWhere($this->searchTerm = $column.entry)->select($row)
        }
```

So I'm a bit stuck and confused on how to actually get the row entry and once it matches the `searchTerm`, to return the entries of the other columns in that row. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE` searches will work, it's just that, they're generally much slower because they have to access the row and not the index. Using wildcards on both sides of the comparator guarantees it won't use the index with a `LIKE`^.

However, if you make the field `FULLTEXT` searchable, you get better search tools, including substring matching. MySQL after 5.6 allows you to use `FULLTEXT` on InnoDB, too.

Borrowing from Frank B's answer, here's something similar. Don't forget to run

```
bin/console d:s:u --force
```

as well.

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(indexes={
       @Index(name="search_idx", flags={"fulltext"}, columns={"col1", "col2", "col3"})
   })
 */
class SomeEntity
{

...

class SomeEntityRepository
{
    public function search($searchTerm)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
            ->where('MATCH(col1, col2, col3) AGAINST(:term IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE')
            ->setParameter('term', $searchTerm)
            ->getQuery()
        ;
    }

...
```

---

**<sup>^ If the term has a wildcard on the right only (`'brown %'`), it *may* use an index for a `LIKE`.</sup>**

Comment: is there a way to avoid adding the columns one by one? Beucase I've plenty of them

Comment: Not sure what you mean adding them one by one (the `@Index()` calls, the `col`'s in the query?).

Comment: yeah the index calls

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in your Repository class.

```
public function search($searchTerm)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->where('r.col1 LIKE :term OR r.col2 LIKE :term OR r.col3 LIKE :term')
        ->setParameter('term', '%' . $searchTerm . '%')
        ->getQuery()
    ;
}
```

and add an annotation to your Entity to add a index on your columns:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(indexes={@Index(name="search_idx", columns={"col1", "col2", "col3"})})
 */
class SomeEntity
{
}
```

And use the CLI to make the changes to your database

> php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Comment: I don't know those `LIKE`s are going to use those indexes. I think a fulltext might: `flags={"fulltext"}` and `MATCH(col1, col2, col3) AGAINST('".escape($searchTerm)."' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)`

Comment: is there a way to it without indexing my entity? Because I have tons of columns and would prefer to keep the same shape of the entity if possible

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'm not sure what you meant, could you elaborate please?

Comment: @Doesitmatter - The more you have, the greater likelihood you'll need indexes. I added another answer.

Comment: This unfortunately also returns an error about ` There is no column with name 'col1' on table 'SomeEntity'.`